# System.Data.DataRowView shows in winforms combobox instead of actual data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

After I load my combobox, it displays System.Data.DataRowView instead of data. I am using the correct column names as returned from the stored procedure (TimeframeDesc and TimeframeCode).

I get the message 'Cannot bind to the new display member' when debugging.

```
        private bool loadTimeframeList(out string msg)
    {
        msg = "";
        string spName = "schemaExec.SelTimeframeCode";
        bool result = true;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(spName);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = _sqlConn;

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter rdr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            rdr.Fill(dt);

            cbTimeframe.DisplayMember = "TimeframeDesc";
            cbTimeframe.ValueMember = "TimeframeCode";
            cbTimeframe.DataSource = dt;             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
            msg = "Could not load Timeframe Codes" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint after `rdr.Fill(dt)` and double check the column names. Make sure there is no leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to check the column names? I don't know what I'm looking for. Thx

Comment: At the breakpoint, in Visual Studio, use the magnifying glass to open the debug viewer for the datatable. Or foreach `DataColumn` in table append the column name to a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Loathing please post as an answer so I can mark it. I used the magnifying glass as you suggested - apparently there were debugging 'SELECT @ whatever' statements in the stored procedure and those results were being returned to the DataTable instead of the actual data.

Comment: Good stuff, answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the breakpoint, in Visual Studio, use the magnifying glass to open the debug viewer for the datatable. Or foreach `DataColumn` in table append the column name to a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that causes your issue but you don't have to use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` before you fill the table. Just:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("schemaExec.SelTimeframeCode", _sqlConn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        da.Fill(dt);
}
cbTimeframe.DisplayMember = "TimeframeDesc";
cbTimeframe.ValueMember = "TimeframeCode";
cbTimeframe.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not your case , but some times it happens when you revert the order, if the datasource was set before the `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` properties. Or was not cleaned from the former datasource.

```
cbTimeframe.DataSource = dt;
cbTimeframe.DisplayMember = "TimeframeDesc";
cbTimeframe.ValueMember = "TimeframeCode";
```

Or

```
cbTimeframe.DataSource = ds1;
cbTimeframe.DisplayMember = "fn1";
cbTimeframe.ValueMember = "fn1";

cbTimeframe.DataSource = ds2; -> here you will get the problem (in the Event of index changed) if u didn't clean the DataSource used .
cbTimeframe.DisplayMember = "fn2";
cbTimeframe.ValueMember = "fn2";
```